# Controlling AVAudioPlayer from AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I want to stop my game music, if the user returns to the game with the iDevice's music player playing.

The AppDelegate.m applicationWillEnterForeground is checking for the Music player successfully, **but I don't know how to tell my AVAudioPlayer to stop, from here.**

Would be really grateful is someone could tell me how to do it? This is giving me a massive headache!

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UInt32 propertySize, audioIsAlreadyPlaying=0;
    propertySize = sizeof(UInt32);
    AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &propertySize, &audioIsAlreadyPlaying);

    if(audioIsAlreadyPlaying){¨
        NSLog(@"iDevice Music is playing!");
        [myAudioPlayer stop];//<<< *** the problemo bit *** :(
    }
}
```

**Page1ViewController.m code, in case it helps:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSError *myAudioSessionError = nil;
    myAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    if ([myAudioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&myAudioSessionError]){
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession created.");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession not created.");
    }

    …
    (if/else statements call the createAudioPlayer method.)
}

-(void)createAudioPlayer{
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^(void){
        NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        NSString *musicFilePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"main_music" ofType:@"aiff"];
        NSData *musicFileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:musicFilePath];
        NSError *myAudioPlayerError = nil;
        //Start the audio player
        self.myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:musicFileData error:&myAudioPlayerError];
        if (self.myAudioPlayer != nil){//Check AVAudioPlayer successfully initiated
            self.myAudioPlayer = self;
            self.myAudioPlayer = -1;//loop continuously
            if ([self.myAudioPlayer prepareToPlay]){
                //(successfully created AudioPlayer)
            }else {
                //(failed to play)
            }
        }else {
            //(failed to initiate an AudioPlayer)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, myAudioPlayer is a property to Page1ViewController, yet in your AppDelegate youre referencing it as if it was declared in the delegate.

you should be getting a reference to Page1ViewControllers audio player to stop.

Unless im misunderstanding something about your code, you should probably be doing something like this.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

......

[self.page1ViewController.myAudioPlayer stop];

......



}
```

Comment: Yeah that's right, but I don't know how to! That is my question. I just typed [myAudioPlayer stop]; to illustrate my problem. How do I do it?

Comment: Just like how you declared myAudioPlayer as a property in Page1ViewController, create a property for your AppDelegate referencing page1ViewController. So in your AppDelegate you can do self.page1ViewController.

Comment: I just tried your code above, and got this code warning error:   Property 'Page1ViewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'  That is basically what I am trying to do though, it is the syntax I am learning. :|

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, If you don't want to create a property of Page1ViewController, you can create a method in Page1ViewController that returns myAudioPlayer to be used in another class like the AppDelegate. Example below..

```
//Page1ViewController.h
@interface Page1ViewController : UIViewController...
....
-(AVAduioPlayer*)currentPlayer;
@end

//Page1ViewController.m
-(AVAudioPlayer*)currentPlayer {
  return self.myAudioPlayer;
}


//AppDelegate.m

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

  [[page1ViewController currentPlayer] stop];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think your solutions will work. One of the problems I have just noticed is that the AppDelegate was not included in ViewController or vice versa. Which SHOULD be done??? ViewController.h in AppDelegate.h, or AppDelegate.h in ViewController.h? :) Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: I thought AppDelegate was connected to the whole app anyway. It is confusing. :|

Comment: It depends on how Page1ViewController is connected to the AppDelegate, my above examples are assuming your Page1ViewController is initialized from the AppDelegate.

Comment: Page1ViewController is inside a NavigationController, using Storyboards. I don't seem to be able to get the AppDelegate to acknowledge the Page1ViewController's AVAudioPlayer but it does acknowledge the page itself.

Comment: Hi skram, I just don't seem to be able to contact the Page1ViewController's objects. I am going to try and create the AVAudioPlayer inside the AppDelegate instead. Thanks very much for your help anyway, much appreciated.